# Odoo 10: Cant see my custom module in top menubar after installing

Tags: module, menu, customization, odoo

I have installed a custom module without any error in my odoo but it doesnt appear in the black top menubar where all other modules are listed.

Below is the screenshot of my menu items from ***User Interface>Menu Items***

[image]

[image]

And below is my Access Rights in odoo :

[image]

Any solution of this problem? I  simply cant work on my module until it appears in the top menubar

Comment: did you assign any action to sub menu's?

Comment: Yes i assigned server action to my submenu :  <record id="view_sim" model="ir.actions.server"><field name="name">Sim Details</field><field name="model_id" ref="model_simcard" /><field name="condition">True</field> <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field><field name="state">code</field><field name="code">if model.sync(): action = {"name": "Sim Details","type": "ir.actions.act_window","res_model": 'simcard',
       "view_type": "form",
                        "view_mode": "tree,form",
                        
                        }
            </field>
        </record>